# Вставить меняющуюся дату в кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Как в кнопку вместо/рядом со стрелками awesome вставить предыдущую и последующую дату, как на картинке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0ab102363e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Стартовая страница</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="col-6 m-5" id="drevleCalendarTop">
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCalendarLeft"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCal">Сегодня</button>
      <button type="button" class="bbtn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCalendarRight"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="drevleCalendarDayOfWeek"> </div>
    <div class="sidebar-box">
      <div id="saints"></div>
    </div>
    <hr id="fastDivisor" />
    <div id="fast"></div>
  </div>

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.10.4/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.10.4/locale/ru.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      var today = dayjs();
      var full_url = "http://calendar.drevle.com/#/" + today.format("YYYY/MM/DD");
      setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));

      function setDate(today) {
        var req = jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://api.calendar.drevle.com/" + today,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(cal) {
            if (jQuery("#drevleCalendarTop").length) {
              var months = {
                "января": "01",
                "февраля": "02",
                "марта": "03",
                "апреля": "04",
                "мая": "05",
                "июня": "06",
                "июля": "07",
                "августа": "08",
                "сентября": "09",
                "октября": "10",
                "ноября": "11",
                "декабря": "12"
              }

              var dayOfWeek = cal.day.dayOfWeek + "<br />" + cal.day.gregorianDate.substr(0, cal.day.gregorianDate.indexOf(dayjs().format("YYYY"))) + " н. ст. <br> (" + cal.day.julianDate.split(" ")[0] + " " + cal.day.julianDate.split(" ")[1] + " с. ст.)";

              jQuery("#linkToDrevleCal").attr("href", full_url);

              jQuery("#saints").html(cal.day.saints);

              jQuery("#linkToDrevleCalCopy").html(jQuery("#linkToDrevleCal"));

              jQuery("#fast").html(cal.day.fast + "<br />" + cal.day.bows + "<br />" + cal.day.dailyFeast);

              jQuery("#drevleCalendarDayOfWeek").html(dayOfWeek);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      jQuery("#drevleCalendarRight").click(function() {
        today = today.add(1, 'd');
        setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
      });

      jQuery("#drevleCal").click(function() {
        today = dayjs();
        setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
      });

      jQuery("#drevleCalendarLeft").click(function() {
        today = today.subtract(1, 'd');
        setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, у Вас в коде всё уже готово. Я добавил лишь несколько строк:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0ab102363e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Стартовая страница</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="col-6 m-5" id="drevleCalendarTop">
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCalendarLeft"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCal">Сегодня</button>
      <button type="button" class="bbtn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCalendarRight"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="drevleCalendarDayOfWeek"> </div>
    <div class="sidebar-box">
      <div id="saints"></div>
    </div>
    <hr id="fastDivisor" />
    <div id="fast"></div>
  </div>

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.10.4/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.10.4/locale/ru.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      var today = dayjs();
      var full_url = "http://calendar.drevle.com/#/" + today.format("YYYY/MM/DD");
      setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));

      function setDate(today) {
        var req = jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://api.calendar.drevle.com/" + today,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(cal) {
            if (jQuery("#drevleCalendarTop").length) {
              var months = {
                "января": "01",
                "февраля": "02",
                "марта": "03",
                "апреля": "04",
                "мая": "05",
                "июня": "06",
                "июля": "07",
                "августа": "08",
                "сентября": "09",
                "октября": "10",
                "ноября": "11",
                "декабря": "12"
              }

              /* Даты на кнопках предыдущего и следующего дней */
              var dBtns = new Date(today);
              dBtns.setDate(dBtns.getDate() - 1);
              var yesterday = dBtns.toLocaleString('ru', { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
              jQuery("#drevleCalendarLeft").html(`<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> ${yesterday}`);
              dBtns.setDate(dBtns.getDate() + 2);
              var tomorrow = dBtns.toLocaleString('ru', { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
              jQuery("#drevleCalendarRight").html(`${tomorrow} <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>`);
              //===

              var dayOfWeek = cal.day.dayOfWeek + "<br />" + cal.day.gregorianDate.substr(0, cal.day.gregorianDate.indexOf(dayjs().format("YYYY"))) + " н. ст. <br> (" + cal.day.julianDate.split(" ")[0] + " " + cal.day.julianDate.split(" ")[1] + " с. ст.)";

              jQuery("#linkToDrevleCal").attr("href", full_url);

              jQuery("#saints").html(cal.day.saints);

              jQuery("#linkToDrevleCalCopy").html(jQuery("#linkToDrevleCal"));

              jQuery("#fast").html(cal.day.fast + "<br />" + cal.day.bows + "<br />" + cal.day.dailyFeast);

              jQuery("#drevleCalendarDayOfWeek").html(dayOfWeek);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      jQuery("#drevleCalendarRight").click(function() {
        today = today.add(1, 'd');
        setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
      });

      jQuery("#drevleCal").click(function() {
        today = dayjs();
        setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
      });

      jQuery("#drevleCalendarLeft").click(function() {
        today = today.subtract(1, 'd');
        setDate(today.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения значений вам надо создать/выделить для них элементы на странице. Например:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCalendarLeft">
   <span class="prevDate"/>
</button>
...
<button type="button" class="bbtn btn-outline-primary" id="drevleCalendarRight">
  <span class="nextDate"/>
</button>
```

Потом, при загрузке страницы, разместить значения. Если использовать те инструменты, который вы используете сейчас, то получится что-то такое:

```js
<script>
    var today = dayjs().locale('ru');
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('.prevDate').text(today.add(-1, 'day').format("D MMMM"))
      jQuery('.nextDate').text(today.add(1, 'day').format("D MMMM"))
    })
    ...
```

Эта же логика точь-в-точь повторяется в функциях, которые обрабатывают клик по кнопке, то есть выбираем нужные элементы на странице и задаем содержание.

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущая дата:
`let prevDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000));`
Следующая дата:
`let prevDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000));`
И потом получить `getDate()` и `getMonth()`